# Скачивание Файлов в С# как можно устранить это исключение?

Tags: c#

Почему-то при попытке запустить вылезает эксепшн "Базовое соединение закрыто: Непредвиденная ошибка при передаче", с чем это может быть связано?

```
    public static string link = "https://bdu.fstec.ru/files/documents/thrlist.xlsx";
public static string fileName = @"C:\Users\Margarita\Downloads\thrlist.xlsx";
public static void Download()
{
    WebClient wb = new WebClient();
    wb.DownloadFile(link, fileName);
}
```

Comment: Проверьте правильность пути еще раз, что путь "C:\Users\Margarita\Downloads\" точно правильный. Я подменил на своего пользователя и у меня файл скачался

Comment: Сейчас проверил еще  раз, файл скачивается, но он почему-то пустой и эксепшн все равно вылезает.